# Direct Sum of Torsion Modules is a Torsion Module

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, direct-sum

I'm trying to prove a rather ambiguous statement:

"Prove that the direct sum of any collection of torsion modules is a torsion module."

This is what I have so far:

"Let $\{M_i\}_{i \in I}$ be a collection of torsion modules.
Additionally, let $m_i \in M_i$ for each $i \in I$ be torsion elements.
Then we have that there exist nonzero $r_i \in R$ such that $r_im_i=0_M$ for each $i \in I$.
Consider $\oplus_{i \in I}M_i$..."

I'm unsure of where to go from here. Any tips?

Comment: Write down what a generic element of the direct sum looks like and then find a multiple that is equal to 0 (hint: the multiplier can depend on which modules the element is composed of).

Comment: (Note: internal direct sums are isomorphic to external direct sums; and an external direct sum is an internal direct sum of submodules isomorphic to the original direct summands; the distinction is, generally, irrelevant)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: The general element of $\bigoplus_{i\in I}M_i$  "looks like" a tuple $(a_i)_{i\in I}$, with $a_i\in M_i$ for each $i$, **and** $a_i=0$ for all but finitely many $i$. So you can find finitely many $i_1,\ldots,i_n\in I$ such that if $j\notin \{i_1,\ldots,i_n\}$, then $a_j=0$ already. That means you only have to worry about making sure you can annihilate $a_{i_1}$, $a_{i_2},\ldots, a_{i_n}$. Can you do that?

Comment: Yes, I figured it out. Thank you!